# Laravel 8 - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel

I tried to install laravel-ide-helper via composer, and it trows me an error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh4EP.png)

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update your composer to latest in terminal by using the command

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: To clarify, you run this before running composer require again.

Comment: Exact, thanks @jrgilman

Comment: Thank you, but it does not help. Same error. I do not think it is in composer. This problem appeared when i installed the newest version Laravel 8.63.0, but in my older project e.g. Laravel version 8.54.0 it works well.

Comment: I add in composer.json package manually and then I ran command composer update and now everithing works.

Comment: Good job @MarekJurica